# Issue with Sitecore 9.0 - Update 2

Tags: upgrade

Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 - Hi All, we are upgrading Sitecore from 8.1 - Update 1 to Sitecore 9.0 - Update 2, while installing the update i.e. **Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (update package for 8.1).update** I am seeing following issue i.e. at the end of the installation, it's trying to delete some files and it's looping the same action. We have provided all necessary permissions to delete the files and disabled custom pipelines configs that we are using. Below the is the error what I am seeing. Could please help me in this?

**Error:**

1. ManagedPoolThread #16 18:03:23 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saving' event.
   Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
   Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
   Source[1]: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler.UpdateReminder(Item item, Boolean force)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaving(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
2. ManagedPoolThread #16 18:05:04 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:deleted' event.
   Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
   Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
   Source[1]: Sitecore.Kernel 
   at Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler.OnItemDeleted(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)

Comment: We need to know the nested exceptions, to have any hope of assisting. You're just posting the event handlers that failed. Please update your question with full information on the errors that are occurring. That said; upgrade questions are really not a good fit for this site - you're better off opening a thread on Community or finding us on Slack.